# Javascript Event handler - why did this work?

Tags: javascript, events, handler

I am new to javascript, as you can tell from the code below. I wanted to create an event handler for 6 buttons that I have on a page. On clicking on a button, the display properties of the block of code below the button changes from "none" to "block". To do this, I needed to associate each button with one single section of html (in this case  tags with unique ids - pt1, pt2, etc).

I struggled with this for a while and got the code below to work. And that is the problem! It turns out that I was going about it completely wrong. But, as a newbie, when it worked I thought that I was on to something. As I spent hours on this, I need to know why the code below worked (so that I will feel that I learnt something). I will highlight the part of the code that I cannot, for the life of me, workout why it worked.

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("CSS");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    // Generate strings associated with the button ids and the event handlers for each button
    var buttonID = "button" + i;
    var clickHandlerID = "clickHandler" + i;
    var buttonEH = document.getElementById(buttonID);
    // Identify the button elements by id

    // As clickHandlerID is a string, to get the browser to recognise it as a function name
    var clickHandler = window[clickHandlerID];

    buttonEH.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
}

/*****************************************************************************/

// Why does this work?
// clickHandler1, clickHandler2, etc are not referenced in my event handler.
// My botched attempt to create them in the event handler (var clickHandler = window[clickHandlerID];)
// resulted in "undefined" values (from console.log(clickHandler)).
// Yet it worked?!?! (I did eventually find the correct approach, a simple 10 line solution,
// but I am troubled that I don't understand what is going on here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!)

/*****************************************************************************/


function clickHandler1 () {
    if (pt1.style.display === "block") {
        pt1.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        pt1.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function clickHandler2 () {
    if (pt2.style.display === "block") {
        pt2.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        pt2.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("CSS");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    // Generate strings associated with the button ids and the event handlers for each button
    var buttonID = "button" + i;
    var clickHandlerID = "clickHandler" + i;
    var buttonEH = document.getElementById(buttonID);
    // Identify the button elements by id

    // As clickHandlerID is a string, to get the browser to recognise it as a function name
    var clickHandler = window[clickHandlerID];
    console.log(clickHandler);

    buttonEH.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
}

/*****************************************************************************/

// Why does this work?
// clickHandler1, clickHandler2, etc are not referenced in my event handler.
// My botched attempt to create them in the event handler (var clickHandler = window[clickHandlerID];)
// resulted in "undefined" values (from console.log(clickHandler)).
// Yet it worked?!?! (I did eventually find the correct approach, a simple 10 line solution,
// but I am troubled that I don't understand what is going on here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!)

/*****************************************************************************/


function clickHandler0 () {
    if (pt0.style.display === "block") {
        pt0.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        pt0.style.display = "block";
    }
}
function clickHandler1 () {
    if (pt1.style.display === "block") {
        pt1.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        pt1.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function clickHandler2 () {
    if (pt2.style.display === "block") {
        pt2.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        pt2.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```css
#pt0, #pt1, #pt2, #pt3 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="button0" class="CSS">button 1</button>
<button id="button1" class="CSS">button 2</button>
<button id="button2" class="CSS">button 3</button>

<div id="pt0">PT1</div>
<div id="pt1">PT2</div>
<div id="pt2">PT3</div>
```

All functions and variables defined at the top-level scope become properties of the `window` object. So `window['clickHandler1']` is equivalent to `clickHandler1`. Your code does:

```
var clickhandler = window[clickHandlerID];
```

when `clickHandlerID` is set to a string like `"clickHandler1"`, `"clickHandler2"`, etc.

Comment: Thank you!! Your answer makes perfect sense.  It does lead to one final question. Why did console.log(clickHandler) give me "undefined" (when placed in the loop after the "var clickHandler = window[clickHandlerID];" statement)? I ask because I suspected that your answer was what was actually happening but the "undefined" return confused me. Thanks again!!

Comment: Oh dear, could it be that I defined the clickHandler functions after the loop? I presume that is what is happening? Honest question!

Comment: No, function definitions are supposed to be hoisted to the beginning. I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: I can't reproduce your console.log problem. I put the code into my answer, with the log statement, and it logs the function properly. I suspect you made a typo.

Comment: Thank you. A typo that cost me a few hours, and much confusion. Glad that I now understand what was going on!!